# How to convert List<Object[]> to Map<String,BigInteger> with Streams & Lambda Java8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have the data as:

```
List<Object[]> result=fromDB();
```

How can I write the code below with Streams in Java 8?

```
Map<String,BigInteger> map= new HashMap<>();
for (Object[] obj : result) {
    map.put((String)obj[0], (BigInteger)obj[1])
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Map<String, BigInteger> map =
    fromDB().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                o -> (String) o[0],
                o -> (BigInteger) o[1],
                (b1, b2) -> b2
            ));
```

Comment: @Rob How are you testing? This works. Your error sounds like a bug of your IDE.

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ 14.0.1, it is throwing compilation error.

Comment: @Rob Yes, that's a bug of IntelliJ then, try to upgrade to the latest version. It works if you compile it on the command line with `javac`.

Comment: Just an observation... When you fetch data from the database, you'll want to preserve order, so `LinkedHashMap` would be the best fit.